# How can I draw inside this for loop in maple?

Tags: maple

I have this code for Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg Method

`while flag = 1 do
 k1 := h*f(t, w); 
k2 := h*f(t+(1/4)*h, w+(1/4)*k1); 
k3 := h*f(t+(3/8)*h, w+(3/32)*k1+(9/32)*k2); 
k4 := h*f(t+(12/13)*h, w+(1932/2197)*k1-(7200/2197)*k2+(7296/2197)*k3);
 k5 := h*f(t+h, w+(439/216)*k1-8*k2+(3680/513)*k3-(845/4104)*k4); 
k6 := h*f(t+(1/2)*h, w-(8/27)*k1+2*k2-(3544/2565)*k3+(1859/4104)*k4-(11/40)*k5);
 R := abs((1/360)*k1-(128/4275)*k3-(2197/75240)*k4+(1/50)*k5+(2/55)*k6)/h; if R <= Tol then 
t := t+h;
 w := w+(25/216)*k1+(1408/2565)*k3+(2197/4104)*k4-(1/5)*k5;
 y := subs(T = t, exact(T)) end if; 
printf(" %4.7f  %4.7f  %7.7f  %7.7f\n", h, t, w, y); 
q := .84*(Tol/R)^(1/4); 
if q <= .1 then h := .1*h 
elif q >= 4 then h := 4*h
 else h := q*h end if; 
if h > hmax then h := hmax end if;
 if t >= b then flag := 0 
elif t+h > b then h := b-t
 elif h < hmin then flag := 0 end if
 end do;`

Now, I want to draw the values of y and w against t. I can't use seq plot because I don't have for loop. In Mathlab we usually open a file and then draw from the data. Here I couldn't do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maple creates a plot all at once, rather than building it incrementally.  What you can do is build up the sequence of points, then plot it.  Thus at the start:

```
tvalues:= NULL;
xvalues:= NULL;
yvalues:= NULL;
```

Then when you have computed t,x,y:

```
tvalues:= tvalues, t;
xvalues:= xvalues, x;
yvalues:= yvalues, y;
```

and after the loop finishes, something like:

```
npoints:= nops([tvalues]):
plot([[seq([tvalues[i],xvalues[i]],i=1..npoints)],
      [seq([tvalues[i],yvalues[i]],i=1..npoints)]], colour=[red,blue]);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for this brilliant answer.